# How do I move a Documentation topic to a question?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I've browsed around Docs.SO a bit, and I found a lot of things that would live better under a question that already exists on the Q&A site. There are often more and better answers to be found in the Q&A. Moving the docs topics there would go along with the idea of letting the best content float to the top *within a relevant context* and without being drowned by good, but not directly related content.

So I suggest giving users the ability to turn Docs topics into answers to existing questions on the site, or even to new questions.

Comment: Most of these docs seem to be less of a reference and more of a Q&A. Example of a great *reference*/documentation site: en.cppreference.com. Example of a bad reference/documentation site: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/488/stdstring#t=201609151542428122111